# Logarithmic-trigonomic inequality $\log_5 \sin(x) > \log_{25} \cos(\frac{x}{2}) $

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, logarithms

$$\log_5 \sin(x) > \log_{25} \cos(\frac{x}{2})$$

I have simplified it to
$$\sin(\frac{x}{2}) \cdot \sin(\frac{x}{2}) \cdot \cos(\frac{x}{2}) > \frac{1}{4}$$

But what should I do next?
I have no idea about next steps!
Thanks!

Comment: what does the comma mean in the bracket?

Comment: What is $\log(25, \cos(x/2))$?

Comment: Thats like logarithm of cos(x/2) with base 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\log_5 \sin(x) = \frac{\log\sin(x)}{\log 5}$$
and
$$\log_{25} \cos(x/2) = \frac{\log\cos(x/2)}{\log 25}$$
so that your inequality reduces to
$$2\log\sin(x) > \log\cos(x/2).$$

This becomes
$$\log\sin^2(x) > \log\cos(x/2).$$

Since the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function, then
$$\sin^2(x) > \cos(x/2).$$

But we have
$$\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x) = 1 - \bigg(2\cos^2(x/2) - 1\bigg)^2 = 1 - 4\cos^4(x/2) + 4\cos^2(x/2) - 1 = -4\cos^4(x/2) + 4\cos^2(x/2).$$

We obtain
$$-4\cos^4(x/2) + 4\cos^2(x/2) > \cos(x/2).$$

Now, set $u = \cos(x/2)$, and get
$$4u^4 - 4u^2 + u < 0$$
$$u(4u^3 - 4u + 1) < 0$$

Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u(4u%5E3+-+4u+%2B+1)+%3E+0), we obtain
$$u > 0.837565$$
or
$$0 < u < 0.269594$$
or
$$u < -1.10716.$$

Therefore,
$$\cos(x/2) > 0.837565$$
or
$$0 < \cos(x/2) < 0.269594$$
or
$$\cos(x/2) < -1.10716.$$
The last inequality is extraneous.

Since $\cos(x/2)$ is decreasing, this means that
$$x/2 < \cos^{-1}(0.837565)$$
or
$$\cos^{-1}(0.269594) < x/2 < \cos^{-1}(0)$$
from which we get
$$x/2 < 0.577985$$ 
or
$$1.297825 < x/2 < \frac{\pi}{2}$$
so that the solution set for the original inequality is

> $$\{x < 1.15597\} \cup \{2.59565 < x < \pi\}.$$

Comment: Why did you use < instead of >? I just can't understand it.

Comment: If the base of logarithm is bigger than one, so log - is increasing function

Comment: Oh, Okey, I've got it

Comment: @Cheburek, please check out my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_{5}\sin (x) > \log_{25}\cos (x/2) \implies \log_{5}\sin (x)>\frac 12 \log_{5}\cos (x/2)$$

$$ \implies  \log_{5}(\sin (x))^2 >\log_{5}\cos (x/2) \implies (\sin (x))^2> \cos (x/2)$$

Now use :

$$\sin^2 y =1-\cos ^2 y=1-\left(2\cos^2\left(\frac y2\right)-1\right)^2$$

Comment: I can't understand why in final stage you get < instead of >

Comment: $\log_5$ - is monotonically increasing function, so I am completely lost in your explanation

Comment: @Cheburek I think my mind was on vacation while I was typing answer.

Comment: Then I've got an equation like in another answer, I can't solve it without using WolframAlpha.

Comment: @Cheburek W|A is the only way to solve a cubic equation, I don't think there is any other way .

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $t=\cos\frac{x}{2}$. As you pointed out,

$$\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}>\frac{1}{4}$$

$$(1-t^2)t>\frac{1}{4}$$

$$4t^3-4t+1<0$$

Then find the real roots of $4t^3-4t+1$.

Comment: We actually have $$\cos\dfrac x2\left(4\sin^2\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2-1\right)>0$$

Comment: But $\cos\frac{x}{2}>0$